# How to keep card-group from wrapping on small screens?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, bootstrap-5

How to keep `cards` in a `card-group` attached next to each other on a smaller screen?

They are attached on lager screen, but separate on smaller screen. I'm hiding the extra cards on a smaller screen and prefer to use the first ones attached.

With this code the `cards` separate under 575px.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="card-group">
    <div class="card">
      ...
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      ...
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      ...
    </div>
    <div class="card d-none d-md-block">
      ...
    </div>
    <div class="card d-none d-lg-block">
      ...
    </div>
    <div class="card d-none d-xl-block">
      ...
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

How to keep showing the first three `cards` attached on small screen?

Comment: By attached do you mean the same row horizontally? i.e., `... ... ...`

Comment: @Kameron, yes, exactly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`card-group` is losing it's `display: flex;` at 575px by default w/ Bootstrap. What you can do to is set the `card-group` to have a flex-display all the time either with CSS or inline Bootstrap classes. You can also look into using the [grid-system w/ rows](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/) However, the parent, `card-group` will still lose flex at 575.

Just add `d-flex` as a class on your parent.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="card-group d-flex">
    <div class="card">
      ...
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      ...
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      ...
    </div>
    <div class="card d-none d-md-block">
      ...
    </div>
    <div class="card d-none d-lg-block">
      ...
    </div>
    <div class="card d-none d-xl-block">
      ...
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```